# Bitcoin daemon sends "Empty reply from server" when in test net

Tags: json-rpc, server, daemon

I'm trying to work with the bitcoin daemon and rpc.

Using the user & password I set I can't connect to it, trying with curl I always get "Empty reply from server".

It works just fine in the real network, I can connect, getinfo, etc, etc...

Is there something I might be missing? the output log in the daemon only shows:

accepted connection 190.xxx:62470
disconnecting node 190.xxx:62470

Thanks!
Javyer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I leave it here. Because i spent about two days on it :-o
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/10218

> Authentication is not optional. Configuring it yourself is optional, but bitcoind never accepts RPC connections without explicitly or implicitly configured username/password.

So, I just added user and pass from file `/root/.bitcoin/.cache`.
And get this:

```
curl --user __cookie__:96fea535b009e62ddffe1c6f5090c50396d17e7f96d0b0a75eb580bdd1771d29 --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```

Comment: Now this file is called `/root/.bitcoin/.cookie`